# PowerShell Out-File

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

I am fairly new to PowerShell scripting.  I have created a very simple script that pipes a couple of commands and displays on screen with different colors for different results.
I want to take the on screen data and put all of it into a txt file, which eventually I'll use for Zabbix alerts.

The script executes and creates the txt file, yet the txt file is empty.
Any assistance would be great!

Code:

```bsh
Get-MailboxServer | Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus | ForEach {
    if ($_.Status.ToString() -notmatch "Mounted" -or $_.ContentIndexState.ToString() -notmatch "Healthy") {
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) - $($_.Status) - $($_.ContentIndexState) - OK" -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) - $($_.Status) - $($_.ContentIndexState) - FAILED" -ForegroundColor Red
    }     
} | Set-Content | Out-File c:\scripts\exchangedb.log
```

Comment: The Write-Host only outputs to the screen, it doesn't store any data to be piped to the txt file.

Comment: Also, `Set-Content | Out-File` doesn't make sense. Use either one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

General rule is that `write-host`, writes only to the host (PowerShell console) and cannot be sent to any other output!
If you would like to create an output and store it into a file, you may use `write-output` cmdlet ... option one. 
Or Option 2: Use two operations: 1. Write-Host and then 2. output to file ..

Also another hint, no need to use match in this case. 
You may try to use `-eq` (equal) or `-ne` (not equal), if you are looking for equality. Note: Those operators do not understand wildcards!
If you would like to use wildcards, then you may check: `-like` and `-notlike`. 
And finally, there is `-match`, or `-notmatch`, which understands also Regular Expressions. 
It is not wrong, but a bit of overhead.

You may check more, about comparison operators here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6

And as you are new to PowerShell, also check any about_ section in PowerShell (or online). In PowerShell console run: `get-help about_` and you will see a huge lists of conceptual topics which are reaaly well written with a great examples. Same could be found online.
Note: You may need to run `update-help` first to geth the full list (About 140+ topics).

And just to mention: Your script logic looks quite fine for a newbie, so keep it up! ;)

Hope it helps!

Best regards, 
Ivan